# Delete word from column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file which have four column 
Like this

```
Freq         ID         Date                                 Name
  0           2053      1998                                apple 
  2           2054      1998 May-June.            orange 
  3           2055      2019                                 apple
  5           2056      1999 Oct-Nov                  orange
```

It is large file and I have to remove  May-Jun from Date column and all which have year with month I have to keep only year 
How can I remove it from python

Comment: Anything you've tried to achieve your goal ?

Comment: Load the table with the CSV module, parse the string of the right column, and keep only the year part ?  We cannot be more specific if you do not explain specifically where you're stuck.  Tell us what you tried to do and what's blocking you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas to read and extract year from date column. you can use `split()` function and split on space the first item will be your year

like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df['Date'] = df["Date"].str.split(" ").str.get(0)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have recently come across the similar kind of problem, I tried to resolve this using below snippet code, you can probable try using it will work and it most optimized solution I think.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from datetime import datetime


to_datetime = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d[:4] , '%Y')
path = "D:\python_poc"
filename="\Input.csv"                 
df = pd.read_csv(path+filename,parse_dates=['Date'])
df = pd.read_csv(path+filename, converters={'Date': to_datetime})
df.to_csv(path+filename,index=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Comment: It will read the file from csv format then converts the date by stripping it and finally update the same file by writing into it. you can choose to write into same file or different file.